# How to copy a string of std::string type in C++?

Tags: c++, string, copy

I used the `strcpy()` function and it only works if I use C-string arrays like:

```
char a[6] = "text";
char b[6] = "image";
strcpy(a,b);
```

but whenever I use

```
string a = "text";
string b = "image";
strcpy(a,b);
```

I get this error:

> functions.cpp: no matching function for call to `strcpy(std::string&, std::string&)`

How to copy 2 strings of string data type in C++?

Comment: Just `a=b;` :D ____

Comment: You should use the `std::string` type and not use `strcpy` but copy assignment.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You shouldn't use `strcpy()` to copy a `std::string`, only use it for [C-Style strings](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson9.html).

If you want to copy `a` to `b` then just use the `=` operator.

```
string a = "text";
string b = "image";
b = a;
```

Comment: and what of strcat () ? is it a=a+"image"; ?

Comment: for strcat you can use a+="image"

Comment: All of strcpy, strcat, strtok etc. are functions of string.h which operator only on c strings i.e. strings that are mere character arrays terminated by a null. If for convenience you have a string object and you still want to use some string.h function, you can call str.c_str() on the string object which basically returns a c string for the contents of the object. However, this is seldom needed because string object has a pretty good api

Comment: @Caesar, please do answer this : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988504/memory-is-corrupted-even-after-pushing-into-the-vector); Thanks.

Comment: If for example I would wish for a copy of string that was "on the stack" (ie. say passed by function call) to be put into a struct that lives on the heap, will this still hold?

Comment: Is it a copy by reference or a copy by value?

Answer (score 22):

strcpy is only for C strings. For std::string you copy it like any C++ object.

```
std::string a = "text";
std::string b = a; // copy a into b
```

If you want to concatenate strings you can use the `+` operator:

```
std::string a = "text";
std::string b = "image";
a = a + b; // or a += b;
```

You can even do many at once:

```
std::string c = a + " " + b + "hello";
```

Although `"hello" + " world"` doesn't work as you might expect. You need an explicit std::string to be in there: `std::string("Hello") + "world"`

Comment: and what is the alternative of strcat for std::string ?

Comment: @Programer You can combine strings using `+`: `std::string a = "text"; std::string b = "image"; a = a+b;`

Comment: @PiotrNycz He asks for copying without specifying copy assignment or copy construction, probably because that distinction doesn't make sense for C strings. New C++ programmers typically don't understand the difference between initialization and assignment anyway, and the syntax is deliberately similar. I don't see any reason for the distinction to matter here.

Comment: @bames53 OP has two string objects of two distinct values, then wants to overwrite one sting by value of other, This is assignment. But this is your answer not mine. I just thought you overlooked this.

Comment: does the copy get mutated if for example the original is reversed?

Comment: @mLstudent33 No, the std::string copy is entirely independent.

Comment: That is very useful coming from Python copy.deepcopy() :)

Answer (score 4):

**strcpy example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str1[]="Sample string" ;
  char str2[40] ;
  strcpy (str2,str1) ;
  printf ("str1: %s\n",str1) ;
  return 0 ;
}
```

Output: `str1: Sample string`

**Your case:**

A simple `=` operator should do the job.

```
string str1="Sample string" ;
string str2 = str1 ;
```

Comment: does that mean it's not possible to cast from one type string to other type?

Answer (score 4):

**Caesar**'s solution is the best in my opinion, but if you still insist to use the `strcpy` function, then after you have your strings ready:

```
string a = "text";
string b = "image";
```

You can try **either:**

```
strcpy(a.data(), b.data());
```

**or**

```
strcpy(a.c_str(), b.c_str());
```

Just call either the `data()` or `c_str()` member functions of the `std::string` class, to get the `char*` pointer of the string object.

The `strcpy()` function doesn't have overload to accept two `std::string` objects as parameters.
It has only one overload to accept two `char*` pointers as parameters.

Both `data` and `c_str` return what does `strcpy()` want exactly.

Comment: " It has only one overload". Is this really true? Isn't it the case that it's no overloads? Or that's how I understood the concept of overload.

Comment: Should you have the urge to use this, take a cold shower and just don't.

The size of the underlying buffer is only guaranteed to be the size of the c-string. Fitting "image" into "text" _might_ work without causing horrible things to happen, but WILL result in the string "imag", since the length of `std::string` is stored and not evaluated by the terminating character.

Plus the second variant will probably not even compile, because `c_str()` returns a `const char *`.