# Memory is corrupted after pushing into the vector

Tags: c++, linux, stl

Why the memory is being corrupted after pushing into the vector. In the below program I have a struct with a string var(it is not a pointer). I am creating a local struct object each time and assigning a string value and push to the vector. After pushing to the vector I am making changes in the local struct object. But this change is being reflected in vector struct object's string data.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <memory.h>

    using namespace std;

    void PushVector(string);

    struct thread_info
    {
            int  id;
            string threadname;
            bool bval;
    };

    std::vector<thread_info> myvector;


    int main ()
    {
            PushVector("Thread1"); // valid data into vector
            PushVector("Thread2");

            struct thread_info print;

            while(!myvector.empty())
            {
                    for(unsigned int index = 0; index < myvector.size(); ++index )
                    {
                            print = myvector.at(index);
                            cout<<"id : "<<print.id<<"\nthread name : "<<print.threadname<<"\nbool value : "<<print.bval<<endl;
                    }
                    myvector.clear();
            }
            return 0;
    }

    void PushVector(const string str)
    {

            std::cout << "Push the thread name to vector\n";
            struct thread_info thread;
            thread.id = 10;
            thread.threadname = str;
            thread.bval = true;
            myvector.push_back (thread); //copying struct obj to vector
            char* p =  (char* )thread.threadname.c_str();
            memcpy(p,"Wrong", 5); //==> Memory corrupting with invalid data after push back. Is it a limitation in C++? 
            thread.threadname = "blabla";  //trying to corrupt directly to string object
    }
```

> o/p:
>       Push the thread name to vector
>       Push the thread name to vector
>       id : 10
>       thread name : Wrongd1   ==> Memory corrupted? why no blabla string?
>       bool value : 1
>       id : 10
>       thread name : Wrongd2   ==> Memory corrupted? why no blabla string?
>       bool value : 1

Comment: You say "even after" as if pushing into a vector magically fixes all memory corruption.

Comment: stomping over the strings memory like that will only result in tears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

**Your `memcpy()` on a `const` pointer (which is undefined behaviour) ran afoul of copy-on-write optimization.**

---

Yes, `vector::push_back()` pushes a *copy* of the object into the vector. So after you `push_back()`ed your local `thread_info` object, changes to the local object should not affect the object in the vector, right?

However, `std::string` is *allowed* to assume that any access to it will happen in a well-defined way. Doing a `memcpy()` to the (`const`) pointer returned by `.c_str()` is not well-defined.

So... let's say that `std::string` took a shortcut when copying the `thread_info` object into the vector: Instead of copying the contained data, it copied the *pointer* to the data, so that two `std::string` objects reference the same memory area.

It can defer the copying to when (and if) it actually becomes necessary, i.e. when one of the strings is written to through any of the defined functions (like `string::insert()` or `operator+=`). This is called "copy-on-write", a rather common optimization.

By casting away the `const` from the return value of `.c_str()` and running a `memcpy()` on it, you foiled this mechanic. Since you did not go through any of the `string` member functions that could have done the copy-on-write, the two objects -- which should be different -- are still pointing to the same data memory.

GDB output, with breakpoint at the last line of `PushVector()`:

```
(gdb) print &thread
$3 = (thread_info *) 0x7fffffffe240
(gdb) print &myvector[0]
$4 = (thread_info *) 0x605040
```

The two `thread_info` objects are different.

```
(gdb) print &thread.threadname
$5 = (std::string *) 0x7fffffffe248
(gdb) print &myvector[0].threadname
$6 = (std::string *) 0x605048
```

The two `string` objects are different as well.

```
(gdb) print thread.threadname.c_str()
$7 = 0x605028 "Wrongd1"
(gdb) print myvector[0].threadname.c_str()
$8 = 0x605028 "Wrongd1"
```

But they point to the same memory area, since neither `string` object is aware that there has been a write access, so no actual copying of the data has taken place.

Answer (score 5):

`memcpy`ing to the result of `.c_str()` is *wrong*. Was the fact that you had to hack away the `const` with a cast not a hint? Which learning resource taught you to do that?

As [paulm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1124744/paulm) so aptly said:

> Stomping over the string's memory like that will only result in tears.

`std::string::c_str()` returns a pointer to a constant buffer that you shall not modify; due to certain optimisations present in some toolchains (e.g. SSO in GCC < 5.0) it may not even be the strings true underlying buffer, which appears to be the case for you here.

**Forget `memcpy`; this is not C.**

At *best*, you could do this:

```
thread.threadname.resize(5);
memcpy(&thread.threadname[0], "Wrong", 5);
```

Or, in C++ code:

```
thread.threadname.resize(5);
std::copy("Wrong", "Wrong"+5, &thread.threadname[0]);
```

But, for reals, you should write:

```
thread.threadname = "Wrong";
```